# Group Elements by Equality

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a standard library function that groups elements by equality.

Example:

`f [1,2,3,1,2,3] == [ [1,1], [2,2], [3,3] ]`

Composing `group` and `sort` does the job:

```
Prelude Data.List> group . sort $ [1,2,3,1,2,3]
[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]
```

But, is there a native function in Haskell's library that can perform the above work in a single function?

I looked at [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html), but did not find such a function.

Comment: Not that I know of.  There isn't a library function for a lot of things, particularly when they're this simple.  However, this implementation isn't necessarily the most efficient depending on the use case.  For example, it might be better to use a `Map Item Int` to build up a count of each of the items, then you can recreate the output of `group . sort` from that map instead.

Comment: My preliminary tests in GHCi (not always the best indicator of optimized performance, but it'll do for now) shows that `last . last . group . sort $ xs` where `xs = take 1000000 $ cycle [1..20]` and has been forced into normal form takes 2.39s and uses a total of 1.483 GB of RAM, while `let counter = Map.fromListWith (+) . flip zip (repeat 1); uncounter = map (uncurry $ flip replicate) . Map.toAscList` : `last . last . uncounter . counter $ xs` takes 0.34 seconds with 369 MB total RAM.  A lot of that RAM is from `xs` itself.

Comment: Using `HashMap` may be even better than just `Map` from `Data.Map`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no such function in `base`. However there is the [`discrimination`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/discrimination) package. In `Data.Discrimination` you will find the following function:

```
group :: Grouping a => [a] -> [[a]]
```

You don't have to write those `Grouping` instances yourself, as there are default methods in place for types that have an instance for `Generic`. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
import Data.Discrimination

data A = A deriving Generic
instance Grouping A
instance Sorting A -- Not necessary for what you are trying to do.
```